# Shopify Script Tag Variables

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

How to get customer variable in script tag installed via admin api ?. I have try {{customer.email}} in liquid and js

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are loading a js via script tag. So, the liquid variable `{{customer}}` won't be available to you. What you can do is add a liquid code via your js which gets interpreted by Shopify and you can then use those variables. Example below:

```
cust_element = '{% if customer %}<span id="current-customer" data-customer-id="{{customer.id}}" data-customer-name="{{customer.name}}" data-customer-email="{{customer.email}}"></span>{% endif %}';
var html = $.parseHTML(cust_element);
var $currentCustomer = $(html).find("#current-customer");
if ($currentCustomer.length > 0) {
  user_id = $currentCustomer.data("customer-id");
  name = $currentCustomer.data("customer-name");
  email = $currentCustomer.data("customer-email");
}
```

Comment: are you sure this works? i've just tried it and it doesn't seem to be doing anything

Comment: The element which has customer data needs to be present in a liquid file so that `{{customer}}` can be obtained. So the span element needs to present in a liquid file for Shopify to parse it and later on your javascript will read those values. You can add the same on the fly. If you can wait i can share a snippet in php you can use

Comment: That would be a huge help if you could! There seems to be a lot of questions asking how to do this/if it's possible but not many answers so a snippet would go a long way